# Hibernate, how to model this relationship

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, hibernate

I have the below tables.

```
create table logical_id_seq (
    logical_id int auto_increment,
    primary key(logical_id)
);

create table mytable (
    physical_id int auto_increment,
    logical_id int not null references parent(logical_id),
    data varchar(20),
    primary key(physical_id)
);
```

The second table uses first table auto-generated value as its value. I am not sure how to model this in hibernate.

I read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone, but I doesn't seem to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually hard to say, I don't know what you want to represent at the object level: is it a one-to-one foreign key association? a many-to-one association? is the association bi-directional? Using an ORM means thinking objects more than tables and it usually help to provide the object model.

I'll assume this is a one-to-one foreign key association. Here is what **Java Persistence with Hibernate** recommends:

> #### 7.1.2 One-to-one foreign key associations
>
> Instead of sharing a primary key, two
>   rows can have a foreign key
>   relationship. One table has a foreign
>   key column that references the primary
>   key of the associated table. (The
>   source and target of this foreign key
>   constraint can even be the same table:
>   This is called a *self-referencing*
>   relationship.)
>
> Let’s change the mapping from a User
>   to an Address. Instead of the shared
>   primary key, you now add a
>   SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID column in the
>   USERS table:
>
> ```
> <class name="User" table="USERS">
>   <many-to-one name="shippingAddress"
>                class="Address"
>                column="SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID"
>                cascade="save-update"
>                unique="true"/>
> </class>
> ```
>
> The mapping element in XML for this
>   association is `<many-to-one>` — not
>   `<one-to-one>`, as you might have
>   expected. The reason is simple: You
>   don’t care what’s on the target side
>   of the association, so you can treat
>   it like a *to-one* association without
>   the many part. All you want is to
>   express “This entity has a property
>   that is a reference to an instance of
>   another entity” and use a foreign key
>   field to represent that relationship.
>   The database schema for this mapping
>   is shown in figure 7.3.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>**Figure 7.3 A one-to-one foreign
>   key association between `USERS` and
>   `ADDRESS`**</sub>
>
> An additional constraint enforces this
>   relationship as a real one to one. By
>   making the `SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID`
>   column unique, you declare that a
>   particular address can be referenced
>   by at most one user, as a shipping
>   address. This isn’t as strong as the
>   guarantee from a shared primary key
>   association, which allows a particular
>   address to be referenced by at most
>   one user, period. With several foreign
>   key columns (let’s say you also have
>   unique `HOME_ADDRESS_ID` and
>   `BILLING_ADDRESS_ID`), you can
>   reference the same address target row
>   several times. But in any case, two
>   users can’t share the same address for
>   the same purpose.
>
> Let’s make the association from User
>   to Address bidirectional.
>
> #### Inverse property reference
>
> The last foreign key association was
>   mapped from User to Address with
>   `<many-to-one>` and a unique
>   constraint to guarantee the desired
>   multiplicity. What mapping element can
>   you add on the Address side to make
>   this association bidirectional, so
>   that access from Address to User is
>   possible in the Java domain model?
>
> In XML, you create a `<one-to-one>`
>   mapping with a property reference
>   attribute:
>
> ```
> <one-to-one name="user"
>             class="User"
>             property-ref="shippingAddress"/>
> ```
>
> You tell Hibernate that the user
>   property of the Address class is the
>   inverse of a property on the other
>   side of the association. You can now
>   call `anAddress.getUser()` to access
>   the user who’s shipping address you’ve
>   given. There is no additional column
>   or foreign key constraint; Hibernate
>   manages this pointer for you.

If what you have is actually a real many-to-one association, it should be pretty easy to adapt the above solution.